# How to type "pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have error running this code and I don't know what the problem is?

```
sedan_classes = ['Minicompact Cars', 'Subcompact Cars', 'Compact Cars', 'Midsize Cars', 'Large Cars']

vclasses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype[categories = sedan_classes, ordered = True]

fuel_econ['Vclass'] = fuel_econ['Vclass'].astype(vclasses)
```

The error message shows:

File "", line 3
    vclasses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype[categories = sedan_classes, ordered = True]
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a function with rectangular braces which is used for indexing. The call would be `vclasses = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories = sedan_classes, ordered = True)` . Check the doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype.html)

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you mark the answer as solved. So other will know you no longer have the problem.